Multiple scripts combined to one script will not run
We had multiple scripts for one sheet and seemed to operate independently but once combined to one script, it seems not to work. It executes but no activity on sheet. Trying to get these on one script so we can add a custom menu to execute the script.
function removeRows() {
  var sheetName = "DBDR_AllDevicesTAB"; // Replace with your sheet name var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName); var range = sheet.getDataRange(); var flVals = range.getFontLines();

  for (var i = flVals.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (var j = 0; j < flVals[i].length; j++) {
      var cellFL = flVals[i][j]; // console.log(cellFL.getFontLine()) if (cellFL == "line-through") { sheet.deleteRow(i + 1); break; // Move to the next row if a strikethrough cellFL is found }

    }
  }
}

function readRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {

    var row = values[i];

    if (row[1].indexOf('Food System') > -1) {
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i) + 1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }

  }
};

function readRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {

    var row = values[i];

    if (row[7].indexOf('Standalone') > -1) {
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i) + 1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }

  }
};


The function readRows appears twice. Does this happen in your Apps Script project, too? It's not clear what you mean by having multiple scripts for one sheet. Please add more details.

I have 3 different files under the same sheet and i tried to combined the files

If you have the same function name in all of them, that won't work. There can only be one function with a particular name. You'll need to rename the duplicates.

If the functions are very similar, you can combine them and use a parameter for the differences. E.g. function readRows(column, match_string), and then if (row[column].includes(match_string))

Aside: there's no need for parseInt(i). i is already an integer, you don't have to parse it.

i <= numRows - 1 is usually written as i < numRows.

Apparently a copy of Delete or Remove Rows based on search data, these codes worked individually but will not work when combined to one script. Why? See Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites.

Use OR Logic
I combined your code into a single function and added a custom menu to easily run the script in the spreadsheet. Kindly copy and paste the code to check if it works on your end.
It removes rows with strike-through text and rows with "Food System" on Column B and "Standalone" on Column H.

Here is the code:
  function removeRows() {
  var sheetName = "DBDR_AllDevicesTAB";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var flVals = range.getFontLines();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var numRows = values.length;
  var rowsDeleted = 0;

  // Remove rows with strikethrough text
  for (var i = numRows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (var j = 0; j < flVals[i].length; j++) {
      var cellFL = flVals[i][j];
      if (cellFL == "line-through") {
        sheet.deleteRow(i + 1);
        rowsDeleted++;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  //Remove rows with Food System or Standalone text
  for (var i = numRows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var row = values[i];

    if ((row[1] && row[1].indexOf('Food System') > -1) || (row[7] && row[7].indexOf('Standalone') > -1)) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i + 1);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }

}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Process Rows', 'removeRows')
    .addToUi();
}


Sample Output:
Before running the script:

After running the script:


References:
Logical Operator
onOpen(e)

Try it this way:
function readRows(index=7,name="Standalone") {
  let d = 0;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues().forEach(r => {
      if (~r[index].indexOf(name)) {
        sh.deleteRow(i + 1 - d++)
      }
  });
}


What is sh? Why have you hard-coded r[0]? One of their functions uses r[1], the other uses r[7].
